# Finding the basis of given subspace of vector space $\mathbb{R}^4(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Let $V = \mathbb{R}^4(\mathbb{R})$ be a vector space. Consider $W =  \{(a, b, c, d)\in \mathbb{R}^4 : a = b + c, ~~ c = b +d\}$. Find a basis and dimension of $W$.

Hint says that basis of $W$ is given by the set $S = \{(1, 1, 0, -1), (0, 1, -1, -2)\}$. It is easy for me to prove that Set $S$ consist of linearly independent vectors and also they generates $W$. Also elements of $W$ satisfies $a = b + c, ~~ c = b +d $.

I want to know what are the general method to find out basis of $W$. How to proceed?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A basis is not unique and it's a bit strange that they simply give you one possible basis as a 'hint'.

If you want to find one yourself, you can start with the given constraints on $a$ and $c$. Note that with $a=b+c$ and $\color{red}{c=b+d}$, so also $\color{blue}{a=2b+d}$, you have that any $\left( a,b,c,d \right) \in W$ is of the form:
$$\left( \color{blue}{a},b,\color{red}{c},d \right)=\left( \color{blue}{2b+d},b,\color{red}{b+d},d \right)=b(2,1,1,0)+d(1,0,1,1)$$
This means that any element of $W$ can be written as a linear combination of $(2,1,1,0)$ and $(1,0,1,1)$, so these two vectors span/generate $W$. If you can show that these two are also linearly independent (this should be easy), then you have found a basis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can't we use matrix methods to solve this problem. Can I construct matrix $A$ from the given condition. So that echelon form of $A$ may give the basis of $W$.